# MySQL - Insert table data from another table

Tags: mysql

i've question about insert query mysql

i want to insert from a table data from another table.
here's my table :

> table 1
>
> id , name
>
> 23 , test_name

and

> table 2
>
> id, code_name , name
>
> 23 , 23 , test_name

i want insert table 2 with kode_name same value with id from table 1
i don't know how to insert with code_name same value id from table 1

how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table2(ID, Code_Name, Name) SELECT ID, ID, Name FROM Table1
```